# AWS Api Gateway Lambda proxy integration, how to get source port from client request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, x-forwarded-for

I'm using AWS Api Gateway to invoke my Lambda functin in proxy mode. Event object contains X-Forwarded-Port information but it contains destination port of client request whereas I need the source port (i.e remote port). I couldn't figure out how to get it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I opened a ticket to AWS support and learned that it's impossible to get source port from API Gateway. The only solution is accepting the port as a parameter of the request.